# Show that the intersection taken over the Gersgorin discs of all similar matrices of $A$ $=$ $\sigma (A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Show that $\bigcap_S G(S^{-1}AS)$ $=$ $\sigma (A)$; the intersection is taken over all nonsingular $S$, and $\sigma (A)$ is the spectrum of $A$.

I'm lost as how to even begin to prove this fact. Any solutions, hints or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, if $A$ is diagonalizable, it is similar to a diagonal matrix, which has very small Gersgorin disks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** we're allowed to use all non-singular $S$.  One non-singular $S$ of particular interest is the $S$ that puts $A$ into its Jordan canonical form (or any upper-triangular form, if you prefer).  For diagonalizable matrices, the Jordan form sufficient.

Otherwise, note that any Jordan block has the similarity
$$
\pmatrix{
\lambda&1\\ 
&\lambda&1 \\
&&\ddots\\
&&&\lambda
} \sim
\pmatrix{
\lambda&1/n\\ 
&\lambda&1/n \\
&&\ddots\\
&&&\lambda
} 
$$
(an analagous, explicitly constructed similarity can be applied to arbitrary upper-triangular matrices).